# Performing operation on 2D array using indices from 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have the following array in python:

`a = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])`

and the following index array:

`b = np.array([0,1,2])`

I want to index a using b such that I can subtract 1 from the matching row/column and get the following result:

`[[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,0]]`

I can do it using loops, wanted to know if there was a "non-loop" way of doing it.

```
for i in range(len(b)): 
    a[i][b[i]] = a[i][b[i]] - 1
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic? This is not clear given the provided output

Comment: The i'th index in the b array corresponds to the i'th row in the a array. The value of the i'th index in the b array is the column of the corresponding row in the a array that 1 will be subtracted from.

Comment: Do you want: `a[np.arange(len(a)), b] -= 1`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code produces output as follows:

```
a = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
b = np.array([0,1,2])
for i in range(len(b)): 
   a[i][b[i]] = a[i][b[i]] - 1
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```

This can be done in non -loopy way as follows:

```
a[np.arange(len(b)),b] -= 1
print(a)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect, it only works with the provided example. It would fail on `b = np.array([2,0,1])` for example.

Comment: Thanks mozway. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: Which is what I already answered ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is some confusion on how to handle this.

You want a simple indexing:

```
a[np.arange(len(a)), b] -= 1
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```

Output for `b = np.array([2,0,1])`

```
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```